# Where is the conflict in versioning for these npm packages?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I try to run `npm install` and I encounter this output:

```
npm ERR! While resolving: my_website@0.1.0                                                                                                     
npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0                                                                                                                          
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^16.14.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-google-maps@9.4.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-google-maps
npm ERR!     react-google-maps@"^9.4.5" from the root project
```

I don't understand the issue. `react@16.14.0` is AFAIU `react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0"`

Why are my versions incorrect?

Thank you,

Slackware

Answer (score 0):

The project is not maintained could you try installing [`@react-google-maps/api`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api) instead

> npm i @react-google-maps/api

[github issue](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/1083)

[github issue 2](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/1071)

Comment: Thank you. Sure. Though that does not answer the question about the issue in resolving the versions.

Comment: @Slackware The project is not maintained, its better to move on to a more latest version! If you want to ignore this, `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: Thank you Naren. I am still wondering why am I getting an error? Is NPM aware of the unmaintained project and gives me an error because of that? I’m really just trying to understand

Comment: @Slackware Its a common error, npm is just a host for opensource packages maybe some maintenance happens, but I am not aware, for now ignore it and continue development I guess